# Let $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$. Prove that if $q,r\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a=qb+r$, then gcd(a,b)=gcd(b,r)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When I was reading the proof of the statement in the title, I encountered a problem.
Here is the proof of the statement:

> Let $q,r\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a=qb+r$. Let $d$=gcd$(a,b)$. Now $d\ |\ a$ and $d\ |\ b$, so $d\ |\ r=a-qb$. Suppose that $c\in \mathbb{Z}$ is such that $c\ |\ r$ and $c\ |\ b$. Therefore, $c\ |\ a=qb+r$, so $c\ |\ d=$ gcd$(a,b)$. So gcd$(b,r)=d$.

My problem is that I understand all the parts except $c\ |\ d$. I can't reach this result from the previous conclusions.
Anyone who helps is appreciated!

Comment: So basically you want to prove that if $c \mid a$ and $c \mid b$, then $c \mid \operatorname{gcd}(a, b)$.

Comment: @Adayah Yes, because the previous steps have already showed that d is a common divisor of $(b,r)$, and by showing that $c\ |\ d$, d becomes the greatest common divisor of $(b,r)$.

Comment: Every common factor of $a$ and $b$ is a common factor of $b$ and $r$ and *vice versa*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that $c|d= \gcd(a,b)$ you can use the fact that $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ that $ax + by = d$. But now $c \mid a$ and $c \mid b$, therefore $c \mid ax + by = d$.

Maybe an easier way to prove the claim is that as $d$ is the **greatest** common divisor of $a,b$, then as $c$ is a common divisor of them we get that $c \le d$. But $c$ is any common divisor of $b,r$, so $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $b,r$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have read the theorem that if $d=$ gcd$(a,b)$, then $ax+by=d$, but I actually forgot it when I was reading this proof :)